# How to convert symbolic expression so it works with curve_fit?

Tags: python, sympy, curve-fitting

so what I'm trying to do is to fit the specific model onto the dataset of `x`-`y` values and get constants of the model. I can get the constant (in this case there is only one) and then the fitted `y_opt`. Below is the working example of doing so:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

data = pd.read_csv(r'')
x_measured = data['x[-]'].values
y_measured = data['y[-]'].values

def y_NH(x_eng, D):
    y_comp = D * x_eng*(x_eng**2 + 3 * x_eng + 3) / (1 + x_eng)**2
    return y_comp

D = curve_fit(y_NH, x_measured, y_measured)
y_opt = y_NH(x_measured, D[0])
```

This works well, but it's not exactly good for me.
The formula for `y_comp` is something I needed to derive manually - originally I had other variable, let's say `Y_comp`, and got y_comp by differentiating `Y_comp` (by `x_eng`, obviously). What I would like to achieve is to feed my function with `Y_comp` (because there will be more like `Z_comp`, `F_comp` etc.), it would differentiate it resulting in `y_comp` (`z_comp`, `f_comp`) and then it would fit the model it onto my dataset - the result then would be constant(s) of the particular model.

I started with some work, but still I am not sufficient and would appreciate some help on this topic. The bugged code is:

```
import sympy as sy
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify

def y_NH2(x_eng, D):   
    lambda1 = sy.Symbol('lambda1')
    x_eng = sy.Symbol('x_eng')
    #Gi = sy.Symbol('Gi')    
    lambda1 = x_eng + 1
    W = lambda1**2 + 2 / lambda1
    y_comp_symb = sy.diff(W, x_eng)
    y_comp = lambdify(x_eng, y_comp_symb,'numpy')
    y_return = D / 2 * y_comp(x_eng)
    return y_return

y_p = y_NH2(x_measured, 12)
print(y_p)
D = curve_fit(y_NH2, x_measured, y_measured)
y_opt = y_NH2(x_measured, D[0])
```

This raises an error in curve_fit that is: "error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats."

Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: I suggest adding the "sympy" tag to this question.

Comment: If you look at the docs of `curve_fit` you see that the first argument of the function is supposed to be the `x`-Data array, but you redefine it to by a `sympy` symbol. I'd guess that the problem is somewhere here. The `f` in the `curve_fit` wrapper is not supposed to take parameters that are not to be fitted. If you need this, you have to use either more low level function like `leastsq` or change to something more general like `lmfit`.